# Access UINavigationController from UIView Subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a subclass of UIScrollView. This custom subclass has a method that is supposed to initialize opening of a new UINavigationController. I understand that subclasses do not deal with this type of approach but how would I handle this kind of scenario in an ideal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the ideal way to handle this would be to declare a custom delegate protocol method for your subclassed `UIScrollView`. You would then set your `UIViewController` which I assume is the parent to the custom scroll view and when it intercepts this delegate callback just do a simple:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: So, once I create a delegate within my subclass I would have to set UIViewController, then pop view controller when needed. But how would I set UIViewController for this delegate? Also, what's the advantage of using delegate rather than setting it within class?

Comment: I guess I described what I would think was the ideal way but not the only way. You could also just make a property in the custom scrollView that will be a reference to the owning viewcontroller and pop that way. The delegate method I described would end up creating a cleaner and more reusable element.

Comment: I'd like to try a delegate. Sorry for persistence but how exactly it will be cleaner and more reusable? Just want to understand.

Comment: So its really about creating your custom class to act as its own unit. The act of poping the owning view controller is appropriate for this situation but maybe there is another situation where you want to do something different.

Comment: It should be up to the owning view controller on how to react so by creating a custom delegate you are having your custom scrollview simply notify its parent that an action is required and the view controller intercepts that and does what it will.

Comment: I agree, the delegation pattern is the way to go here... In general, a child object/controller shouldn't know much about its parent. This helps to keep classes separate and keep your code cleaner. The way delegation is implemented in iOS is using `@protocol` declarations... see Wiki on delegation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) and this tutorial too (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates)